# How do I modify Plain Text Content Control in Word via MS Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, excel-2016, contentcontrol

I am using MS Excel VBA to copy Cells from Excel to Word. I established Plain Text Control Fields in my Word Document and add Values from my Excel Document.

Before I add them via VBA code, I open the Word Document and activate it (like in the code below).

Now there are quotation marks in my plain text control fields after inserting the copied text. I want to replace quotation marks in Content Control Object (3) with "space".

Why do I not just delete it manually? Because I established drop down fields in my Excel Document and change them quickly. After changing them I generate new Values and insert them again in my word document.

I hope someone can tell me, how to use 'Find """" and Replace "" Command correctly for specific content control objects.

I looked up every single page in the internet, but I couldn´t find any specific commands which I can apply on content control objects. I appreciate all the answers:)

```
Sub InsertValuesinContentControls_ ()

Dim wdapp As Object
Dim wddoc As Object
Dim strdocname As String


On Error Resume Next

‘If my word doc is not open yet

Set wdapp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If Err.Number = 429 Then
Err.Clear
Set wdapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

wdapp.Visible = True

strdocname = "C:\Users\Userxx\File\NameofDocument.docm"

'activate the word doc
wdapp.Activate

Set wddoc = wdapp.Documents(strdocname)

If wddoc Is Nothing Then Set wddoc = wdapp.Documents.Open(strdocname)


'Now I copy single cells in my plain text controls which I established in Word

Worksheets("Generator").Range("F5").Copy
wddoc.ContentControls(1).Range.Paste

Worksheets("Generator").Range("B5").Copy
wddoc.ContentControls(2).Range.Paste

Worksheets("Generator").Range("A11").Copy
wddoc.ContentControls(3).Range.Paste

With wddoc.ContentControls(3)
.Replace What:=””””, Replacement:=””, Lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False

End with


End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is missing some important information. Please use the [edit] link to include *in the question*: 1) **How** the code is not working and 2) the text in the content conrols (best to copy/paste a couple of examples as text into the question) - we need this for testing purposes.

Comment: FWIW, though, you can't use Excel's Find/Replace in Word. You need to use **Word's** find/replace. There are literally hundreds of examples on Stack Overflow, alone, for Word's Find/Replace, including using it from Excel. You could also record a macro in Word to get the basic syntax.

Answer (score 0):

sadly I can't comment yet, but did you try with:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/finding-and-replacing-text-or-formatting

talking about

```
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find 
 .ClearFormatting 
 .Font.Bold = True 
 With .Replacement 
 .ClearFormatting 
 .Font.Bold = False 
 End With 
 .Execute FindText:="", ReplaceWith:="", _ 
 Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll 
End With
```

You shuld use `.find` on active document - word, then clear formating and set

```
.Execute FindText:="", ReplaceWith:="", _
Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Hope I've helped.
Have a great day.

Comment: Thank you for answering. 

I tried it but it didn´t work out for a few reasons. 

1) I want to write the code in MS Excel VBA and not Word, so I have to activate wddoc.
2) It will always Find Text in my whole Word Document, so I can´t just select a specific content control field.. which sucks a bit but I think, Microsoft doesn´t have a solution for that yet. 

I right now wrote the .Execute FindText.. Code in Word and transform it there.